# Java interface Method

Tags: java, interface

According to the code specified below, b.fun2() is not allowed in main method, I know why it is not working. I wonder that how can I solve these kind of problem. According to the solid programming principle, I need to write an interface for my problem. But this problem prevent me to define an interface.

```
public interface A{
   void fun();
}
public class B implements A{
     void fun(){
          // some code
     }
}
public class C implements A{
     void fun(){
          // some code
     }
     void fun2(){
          // some code
     }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

             A b = new C();
             b.fun2(); 

    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to be able to call the methods of `C`, why not just declare the variable as type `C` instead of `A`?

Comment: the problem is, you've declared it as type A, which doesn't contain method fun2

Comment: And it  has nothing to do with being in the `main()` method. The code you wrote would be wrong anywhere.

Comment: Its more likely a design issue rather than coding issue IMO. Need to think about why `A` is without method `fun2()`, or why `b` is type `A`. Using interface is for implementing it with more than 1 implementation. Change in  both codings will result in a new design.

Answer (score 2):

General rule here is: using interface reference that is referencing implementing class object you can call only those methods which have been overridden by the implementing class.

To make your code work do:

```
C c = new C();
c.fun2();
A b=c;
```

PS: Another problem here is, By default all members of interface are public. so when overriding fun() in classes B and C, the visibility of this method is getting reduced to default level from public; this action is not valid in Java. Use **public** access specifier whenever overriding interface methods.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have fun2 in A so you can't call to it by using object which reference type is A. To fix this put fun2 abstract method in A interface.

Comment: their members are implicitly public.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access the method `fun2` from the class `C` you should make a cast to the class `C`, like this: `((C) b).fun2();` instead of `b.fun2();`

It is always reasonable to test whether or not your object is an instance of the class C before making the cast, this way not generating any error. An example:

```
if(b instanceof C) {
     ((C) b).fun2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `fun2` is not part of the interface - you're assigning to an `A` which does not have that method. You can do

```
C b = new C();
```

then you can call `fun2` on that.

Or add `fun2` to the interface:

```
interface A {
    void fun();
    void fun2();
}
```

Or extend the interface to keep `A` itself unchanged:

```
interface A2 extends A {
    void fun2();
}
class C implements A2 {
}

A2 b = new C(); 
b.fun2();
```

Answer (score 0):

As fun2 is not declared in interface A. You cannot call the fun2 defined in class C using the reference of type A. To call the fun2 using A type reference you have to downcast the reference to child class C.
You can tweak this code to call fun2 using reference of type A.

```
if(b instanceOf C)
   ((C)b).fun2();
```

Answer (score -1):

Define fun2() in the interface A, but override it in your implementing classes.

```
    public interface A {
        void fun();
        void fun2();
     }

    public class C implements A{
        void fun(){
       // implementation code
        }
        void fun2(){
      // implementation code
       }
     }
```

Comment: bad solution. now you force the other implementing classes to define fun2 as well